# How to set tooltip color according to updated point color of series data in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

tip according to my updated point colour not series colour.

Here is my custom function:

```
             function myFormatter() {

                     console.log(this);
        //alert($(this.graphic.element).attr('fill'));
        if(this.series.name == 'Series 2'){
            return '<div style="color:Black;"><b>Target Line</b></div>';
        }else if(this.series.name == 'Series 3'){
            return '<div style="color:Red;"><b>Danger Line</b></div>';
        }else{
            return '<span style="color:'+ this.series.color + '"><b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
            this.x +': '+ (<?php echo round($this->targetVal,2);?> + parseInt(parseFloat(this.y).toFixed(2))) +' Kg</span>';
        }
      }
```

and tooltip is

tooltip: {
                    useHTML:true,
                    formatter: myFormatter
                }

Answer (score 0):

Well it is strange, because I reproduced your example in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Ykhx/3/

```
 formatter: function () {

            //alert($(this.graphic.element).attr('fill'));
            if (this.series.name == 'Series 1') {
                return '<div style="color:blue;"><b>Target Line</b></div>';
            } else if (this.series.name == 'Series 2') {
                return '<div style="color:red;"><b>Danger Line</b></div>';
            } else {
                return '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '"><b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + parseInt(parseFloat(this.y).toFixed(2)) + ' Kg</span>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think u didn't get my points please check the links 1)http://jsfiddle.net/TechiesJyoti/SneWB/1/ 2)http://jsfiddle.net/TechiesJyoti/pSJ3s/ Here U will get the details of my question , means I needs the tool-tip according to the points colour so its urgent please help me out